# IBOutlet instance variables in implementation (.m) files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let’s say I have a view controller, or a window controller, which is (as usual) the “File’s Owner” in a corresponding XIB file.

It is (as you all know) very common to have `IBOutlet`s in the controller class that you can then connect in the XIB using Interface Builder.

Until now, I have been creating `IBOutlet` instance variables in my interface (.h) files. But (as you all know) `IBOutlet`s are very often a private mechanism of the controller class; outsiders shouldn’t even know about them.

This is why I now—since Objective-C recently started offering the capability to do so—want to put all of my `IBOutlet`s into my implementation (.m) files.

I tried doing this, and this seems to work fine. **My questions are these:** Why does this work? I was under the impression that Interface Builder could only view the class’ header files—not peek into their implementation files. Am I wrong? How come that Interface Builder can “see into” implementation files? Could it be potentially dangerous to put `IBOutlet` instance variables into the implementation files?

Comment: Note that this is only possible when using the modern runtime on the Mac, which means 64-bit only. The classic runtime requires all ivars to be declared in the header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Xcode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html)

> Note: Because Xcode 4 parses both your header files and implementation
>   files for indexing, you can define actions and outlets in
>   implementation (.m) files without needing to place them in the header
>   file and you can make connections directly from the nib file to the
>   implementation file. Therefore, you do not need to expose parts of
>   your interface or actions to clients who might be using your classes.

And for **Could it be potentially dangerous to put IBOutlet instance variables into the implementation files?**

Yes it is, but not that much as any declared method can be accessed because of the lack of access-scope at runtime. Even if the method isn't accessible, the resolution is done at runtime and no access-scope information is attached to the method.
That could have been implemented, but Objective-C lacks of `private`, `protected` and so on as in C++ or Java.
Note that implementing such a behavior would be even much slower at runtime.

Comment: Could you explain why using IBOutlet ivars in implementation files is potentially dangerous?

Comment: Because it means that some of your code intentionally access your private data which is by design dangerous and against OOP paradigm

Comment: @Geoffroy, so you think it’s a bad idea to have `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s be in the implementation file only?

Comment: As outlet and action are designed to be accessed and called from outside, they should be declared in the header file. The header file is the interface (it's quite explicite in obj-c) by which you access the object, you rarely try to change the object internal structure, or some code may crash on unexpected value.

Comment: Could a XIB/controller pair be an exception to this rule? If only the XIB needs to know about an outlet or action — and no other *classes* — isn’t it actually a nice encapsulation principle to put the outlet or action into the implementation file?

Comment: As it is against OOP principle, I wouldn't say that it's a nice principle, but it's still useful in some cases :) That a bit the same as `friend` relationships in C++, so why not but try to limit it to the strict minimum, for clarity sake.

Comment: I don't really understand why this is against OOP principles. IBOutlets and IBActions are intentionally used privately in the class that has declared them. I have never seen one being accessed from outside, and if that happens I regard it as a bad design itself. @Geoffroy can you please elaborate more on this ?

Comment: @pe60t0 The IBOutlets/Actions are generally accessed from a graphical interface, which is parsed by another piece of code. This code will thus reference methods and properties you defined as "private". It somewhat breaks the encapsulation principle. If your code has to be accessed from the outside, declare it publicly. If you don't want people to mess with it, comment it.