# Button and segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a beginner's question.

I have a view with a button, which switches to another view by a segue.

In that case, must this button be declared in `ViewController.h`, like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *calculate;
```

or is it optionnal?
I remark that the segue transition works without button declaration.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you can connect outlet in .m file too if you are not accessing out of the class. In common programming practice & for programming beauty we keep all outlet in .h file. Look inot this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719118/iboutlet-instance-variables-in-implementation-m-files

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you do ***not*** need to connect the button to an `IBOutlet`.

Not-so-short-answer: You only need to create an `IBOutlet` for objects that you want to reference from code. Such as if you wanted to change the Title on the button for some condition. This would have no effect on your Segue connection.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is **optional** if you don't want to access the instance of the button in your code (of course, you can still access it with `viewWithTag` or by getting the subviews of the main view, but it's much cleaner with a declaration).

Answer (score 0):

You don‘t need an outlet here.

The IBOutlet doesn‘t declare the button. The button is created by the XIB or Storyboard file. An Outlet is simply a name under which the XIB/Storyboard-loading mechanism will store the address of the button so you can modify its title or whatever.

If you create a button yourself, you have its address, but if the button is created by the XIB, you need some other way to get individual objects‘ addresses out. That‘s what an IBOutlet is for.